# How to check if postgres is indexing concurrently?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, indexing

I have a written this migration to index concurrently:

`add_index :table_name, %i[field1 field2], algorithm: :concurrently`

How do I check if indexing is happening concurrently for new records insertion and update operation?

Answer (score 1):

Any currently executed statements are visible in `pg_stat_activity.query` column. So you can verify it there. More. This type of index is visible in metadata, but it is flagged as `INVALID` until the creating is done.